# Read Xml Data and store in Text file Dynamically

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing

I need to read XMl Data and store it in Text File, In the above code i am hard Coding getTagValue for all the Tag Names, If they are 4 tag names i can hardcode getTagValuebut now i had 200 tags and how can i read data into text file without hard coding  getTagValue

Comment: What is your problem? What doesn't work?

Answer (score 0):

When using DOM to parse the XML you must know the exact structure of the XML, so ther is no real way to avoid what your are doing.

If you have an XSD (if not you can write one), you can generate a Java object from it using some Xml binding framework like [XmlBeans](http://xmlbeans.apache.org/) and then with one line you can parse the XML and start working with regular java object.

A sample code would be:

```
File xmlFile = new File("c:\employees.xml"); 

// Bind the instance to the generated XMLBeans types.
EmployeesDocument empDoc = 
    EmployeesDocument.Factory.parse(xmlFile); 

// Get and print pieces of the XML instance.
Employees emps = empDoc.getEmployees(); 
Employee[] empArray = emps.getEmployeeArray(); 
for (int i = 0; i < empArray.length; i++) 
{ 
    System.out.println(empArray[i]); 
}
```